# Android: Failure delivering result ResultInfo. Intent is apparently null?

Tags: android, file, audio, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to have the user pick an **audio file** and store the path of that audio file. I'm doing so by using an **ACTION_GET_CONTENT Intent** so the user can pick an application to choose the file with. For some reason though, in the **onActivityResult** method, the **Intent data** is being returned as **null**, as is shown in the error message. Logcat error message and relevant code is given below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**MAJOR EDIT:- This error only occurs when I press the back button or CANCEL ! Choosing a music file actually works fine. Sorry about that. Nonetheless, the error persists.**

LogCat Error:-

```
06-26 16:36:25.238: E/AndroidRuntime(24759): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.packagename.appname.activityname}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Call to chooser activity placed in a method which is invoked in onCreate():-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("audio/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, audioreminder);
```

onActivityResult() method:-

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    SharedPreferences flags = this.getSharedPreferences(
            "screen_on_flags", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = flags.edit();
    String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
    switch (requestCode) {
    case audioreminder: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            editor.putString("audioreminderpath", FilePath);
            editor.commit();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            CheckBoxPreference other_audioreminder = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("other_audioreminder");
            other_audioreminder.setChecked(false);
            }
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used, this code..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Gallery"), audioreminder);
```

Also, in `onActivityResult()` check `Intent data` either is null or not

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(data != null)
    {
    SharedPreferences flags = this.getSharedPreferences(
            "screen_on_flags", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = flags.edit();
    String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
    switch (requestCode) {
    case audioreminder: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            editor.putString("audioreminderpath", FilePath);
            editor.commit();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            CheckBoxPreference other_audioreminder = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("other_audioreminder");
            other_audioreminder.setChecked(false);
            }
        break;
    }
   }
  }
 else
 {
 Log.e("Intent data:" , "null")
 }
}
```

Try this and let me know what happen..

Comment: Then just check **Intent data is not null** in onActivityResult() as I mentioned in my answer..

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I've tried the code and the log is indeed showing Intent data to be null. There is no longer a force close but unfortunately, this means the code in the else if statement (i.e.resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED) will never be executed. I guess I can just shift the code to where the log statement is and it'll work. Any idea why data is null? =) Thanks again for your time. You've already answered my question so I've chosen it as the answer ^^

Comment: Actually, resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED was worked but in your case you are getting intent data before it, so its causing exception..

Comment: Yes, exactly. When I press cancel though, data is being returned as null. If I choose a music file, data is not  null. So since data is always being returned as null when I press back or cancel, the app will never even try to execute RESULT_CANCELED code. What I don't understand is why pressing Cancel is returning a null intent. Am I thinking about this right? A little bit confused.

Comment: Also, maintain your switch case in onActivityResult(), because when you press back then its come in case: RESULT_CANCELED  as always your gallery app return null if you press back without choosing any file from it.

Comment: That is the problem. It should run as you say but it doesn't. When I press back or cancel, RESULT_CANCELED is not executed. Log.e is executed. It doesn't make sense. I can work around it, no problem, but for the sake of understanding, it just doesn't make any sense. =(

Comment: OH I got it. It turns out that RESULT_CANCELED is needed because not all application return null for the data Intent. For example, media selector returns null so RESULT_CANCELED will not be executed but my file manager does not return null so the if-else statement still does need to be there. Simple solution was to copy the code in RESULT_CANCELED if statement to the outside else statement containing the log so that it works for every possible case, since I'll let my user choose how they want to pick the audio file. Thank you so much for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

No, what the error says is that your `onActivityResult()` method threw a `NullPointerException`, not that the data is necessarily `null`. You need to debug to see where the error is in your method.